# Display a webpage on a TV using Chromecast without a casting device

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromecast

Is it possible to use Cromecast to just display a certain webpage without this page being mirrored from a device?

I want to show some data on a TV. I currently use a TV which is connected through an HDMI cable to a laptop which displays a powerpoint presentation. I want to replace this with a TV+chromecast connected to a WiFi network.

I'm able to initiate the process (entering url?). But I should then be able to leave the room/building with the TV just displaying the webpage.

It's seems fairly basic, but I can only find solutions to mirror things from a device.

If not possible with Chromecast, are there any other solutions?

Comment: Have you tried anything and is not working? There are a number of different approaches you can take; the simplest one is just to send a url to your own receiver and then have an iframe in your receiver to go to that url.

Comment: What do you mean by 'receiver'? I also want to clarify that I don't own a Chromecast yet. I'm trying to figure out which solutions is best for me.

Comment: You may want to read on how cast works on our documentation site (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers) to see what a "receiver" is.